# How to get error messages in English in golang?

Tags: windows, go, runtime-error, non-english

When I run a program in go, in a W7 in Spanish, I get error messages in the SO language.

To provide an example:

```
2017/12/15 08:11:28 listen tcp :8080: socket: Se ha proporcionado un argumento no válido.
```

What can I do to get messages like this in English?

I emphasize that my need is not to have translated this specific message, but have the 'standard' English error in order to search for a solution.

Comment: 1. Translate it yourself (offline or via a translation service). 2. Contact the original author of library (if the message is from such a lib). 3. Change OS language if this stems from your os. So basically nothing. Sorry.

Comment: What is generating the error?

Comment: You need to give a bit more detail here - What is the program? what are the arguments given to it? Are you compiling it or an end user?

Comment: The program is not important, because I want to have ALL error messages in English. This is a run-time error, and I need the EXACT English error to successfully search it to found the cause. I emphasize that my need is not to have translated this message, but have the 'standard' English error in order to search for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means *An invalid argument was provided*, it is partly in english, so probably just the last bit was added by the program. What is the program and how are you calling it? It's possible the message comes from the OS, the program or libraries used by the program, but most likely it comes from the program concerned.

Assuming you compiled the program, search for that string in your source code, *including libraries*, and change it to your desired string, then recompile.

Comment: I don't need help with this specific error. The program of this example doesn't have more than a dozen lines. It'll help to know from where the error comes, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Give more detail to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're running your server in a linux box, which might be set to spanish language.  Supposing you'd like to keep like this, a good way to get rid of that is using something like this when you run the server:

```
bash$> LANG=en_IN ./your_fancy_server
```

Note that it impacts in all language set, like number, date and time formats.  More about that and how to isolate each of them [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-locales-i18n-on-a-linux-unix/)

Another option is using something closer to golang style, like [go-i18n](https://github.com/nicksnyder/go-i18n), and parse all the error messages.

My personal note here (it's just my personal opinion instead of a universal truth), but if I were you I would set my server to English language and do the properly treatments inside the software, and no, English is not my first language.

Last but not least, if you're on Windows, sorry, it won't help you.  Next time please give as much details as possible, the more the better.

Comment: In Linux is as easy as you comment, but not in Windows. I've a W7, with no chances to change. If I use a cygwin console and running the program with LANG=C doesn't work.

Comment: Cool, it looks like there are some work around using the kernel32.dll where, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051(v=vs.85).aspx, but I'm not sure it this is the bet approach, I would create an account just to run this service setting the properly language and locale things, like number, date and time format, or if it was just for a dev env using WSL is another good choice